# CakePHP form validation before sending post to the requested controller function

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

My validation is working as it stands, but I want to display the validation error prior to the search controller. I understand this might not be possible within the CakePHP framework.

I have a model **plan.php**.  And in the **plans_controller.php**, I have a function called **search()**.

My form calls **search()** as expected (because there is no search model):

```
echo $this->Form->create('Plan', array('action' => 'search'));
```

As it stands, when I submit my search, the errors are displayed and the url changes to .../search, so no results are displayed ("There are 0 results for that search criteria", but the correct validation errors are displayed below required form fields.

I do not want the .../search url to be displayed. I want the form to "halt" and just display the validation errors w/out changing the url to the search function.

I am calling the search form within an element because the search form displays on several different pages.

To sum this up: The search form should validate w/out changing the url path to the controller action name of the search. Of course, the validation is done IN the search() and plan.php model, so I just don't know how to work around this and wondering if its even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `validates()` method of the model to check whether it validates and then redirect back.

Assuming your model is called Plan, this would be your controller

```
$errors = array();
if (!$this->Plan->validates($this->data)) {
   //errors occured
   $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
   $this->Session->save('Plan.errors', $errors);
   $this->redirect('/plans');
}
```

And in your view.

```
if ($this->Session->check('Plan.errors')) {
   $errors = $this->Session->read('Plan.errors');
   $this->Session->delete('Plan.errors'); //don't want it again

}
```

In both cases, make sure Session helper/component is actually assigned to your view and controller

Comment: JohnP, interesting approach. Yours is much more elegant than mine. I will give it a shot : )

Comment: I've used cakePHP 1.3s way of getting the helper in the view, in case you're having trouble there.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Cracked out a working solution w/ implode, but now my errors are only displayed in the default layout and no longer under the form fields where that belong.. So now I need to know how to get the errors back below the form fields..

Working code:

```
...else {
          $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
          $error_messages = implode(' ',$errors);
          $this->Session->setFlash($error_messages);
          $this->redirect('/');
        }...
```